# How to record movement over time, Having a playback of the mouse movements?

Tags: java, swing, time, awt, mousemove

I am trying to record the mouse movements over time and see them over playbacks (Possibly Video, that is edible). I need to be able to retrieve the exact position of the mouse in coordinates when given a specific time.
Ex: Mouse movement is recorded for 20 seconds. I need to get the location of the mouse at 10.6 seconds.

What is the best way to store these mouse coordinates over time?
And the best way to play make a video to have an entire playback?

To obtain the coordinates of the mouse, I am using Java's official mouse motion listener https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mousemotionlistener.html

```
public class MouseMotionEventDemo extends JPanel 
                                  implements MouseMotionListener {
    //...in initialization code:
        //Register for mouse events on blankArea and panel.
        blankArea.addMouseMotionListener(this);
        addMouseMotionListener(this);
        ...
    }

    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
       saySomething("Mouse moved", e);
    }

    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
       saySomething("Mouse dragged", e);
    }

    void saySomething(String eventDescription, MouseEvent e) {
        textArea.append(eventDescription 
                        + " (" + e.getX() + "," + e.getY() + ")"
                        + " detected on "
                        + e.getComponent().getClass().getName()
                        + newline);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd start by just storing the MouseEvent and timestamp in a LinkedList.

Comment: *"And the best way to play make a video to have an entire playback?"* This is a very different question from the original one asked. It should be on its own Q&A thread.

Comment: @SteveSmith, I was worried if the computer would be able to process them in time because of many abrupts movements generated by the mouse, I am possibly going with this approach but have some intervals (EX, every I will get the coordinates for every 2 actions that was invoked)

Comment: There's only one way to find out if the computer can cope. :)   I shouldn't think it will be a problem though, since the `MouseEvent` object is created automatically for every mouseMoved() call anyway, whether you store it or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MouseEvent class has methods such as `getX()` respectively `getXOnScreen()`, and the same for the Y axis.

One way to go about this: create a class that contains the information you need, like:

```
class SimpleCoordinate {
  private final int x;
  ...
```

and then in your main program:

```
List<SimpleCoordinate> coordinatesHistory = new ArrayList<>();
```

and in your listener do:

```
coordinatesHistory.add(new SimpleCoordinate(...))
```

What exactly you store in your class is up to you. Could be just "coordinates", but it might also sense to add some sort of timestamp.

The key problems to carefully consider/design/test:

- how "granular" is that mouse listener (like when you move the mouse really fast, how many events do you get)
- how long is that program supposed to record (if it is supposed to record days or weeks of user activity, you might run out of memory, by just adding that information to memory)

Of course, alternatively, you could push the records into some "queue", and have another thread regularly fetch elements from the queue, to somehow persist them.

Comment: yes, I agree! Initially, I thought of the same approach, but the speed of the mouse may be too fast sometimes for the program to record.

Comment: Worst case is I count 1 response for every 2 response in hopes of downing the number of inputs.
Since this is probably the most likely approach to go, I'll be closing this with your answer!